# Get current user name autoit

Tags: autoit

I try to get the name of the current user logged like that

here my code

```
local $IniRead = IniRead(@AppDataDir & "\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini", "Profile0", "Path", "default")
MsgBox(0, "", "valeur : " & @AppDataDir & "\Mozilla\Firefox\" & $IniRead)
```

But i use a #requireadmin so i got the name of the runas and not the name of the logged session in windows...

i can't leave the #requireadmin cause i use it for make a Filecopy...

if someone got a way.

Comment: Or if someone got the solution for RunAS a filecopy...

Comment: Using #requireadmin will ONLY give you the admin rights. You got something wrong.
If you want to read current user of firefox session you cant get it in a way you tried.

Comment: i know but now i try to make a runas with comspec, if u got a way...

Answer (score 1):

You can use @UserName to get the running user.  Milos is right, the #RequireAdmin directive directs AutoIt to request the admin token from the Operating System.  If the logged on user is an administrator, it will either prompt them to continue, or continue silently depending on UAC.  If the logged on user is not an administrator, they will be prompted for an account with administrative credentials.

If you're looking to copy a file into @AppDataDir, you will not need administrator rights since the logged on user will have full access (by default) to @AppDataDir.